# jsp iant showing content of mysql table

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to jsp and i tried to connect my database with jsp and to show the content of my table on the jsp but it ia not getting there. Please tell me where am i going wrong?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<% 
String roll=request.getParameter("roll");
String driver="com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
String connectionUrl="jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database="try";
String userid="root";
String password="password";
try{
    Class.forName(driver);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}        
Connection conn=null;
Statement stmt=null;

%>

<html>
  <body>
   <h1>STUDENT RECORD</h1>
   <table border=1>
     <tr>
      <td>Roll</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Trade</td>
      <td>Semester</td>
      <td>Update</td>
     </tr>

<%
try{
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+database,userid,password);
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    String s="select*from student";
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(s);
    while(rs.next()){
%>
     <tr>
      <td><%= rs.getString("roll") %></td>
      <td><%= rs.getString("name") %></td>
      <td><%= rs.getString("trade") %></td>
      <td><%= rs.getString("sem") %></td>
      <td><a href="update.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("roll")%>">UPDATE</a></td>
      </tr>
<% 
    }
    conn.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
   </table> 
  </body>
</html>
```

and i am getting a result shown in the image. I'm using eclipse mars jee and mysql database. Tomcat 8.0 as server.[image][image][image]

Comment: You just wanted to fetch the data when JSP page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into my code, and see where you were wrong

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo","root","root");  //Connecting to the database
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");  // fetching data from student table
    %>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Roll</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Trade</th>
            <th>Sem</th>        
        </tr>
        <% 
            while(rs.next())
            {
                %>
                <tr>
                        <td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>   // you can use column name instead of index
                        <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                        <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>       
                </tr>
                <%
            }
        %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain me this..!

Comment: @rango please tell me which part of code you don't understand, so that I can explain you

Comment: thanks for your help but i got my fault . I have written jbdc instead of jdbc.